# Why does this page display differently in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am struggling to see the reason why this page:
http://dev.originaleye.co.uk/originaleye/
displays correctly in IE7 but not IE8.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When you say "diaplay Correctly", you have to be more specific. What is right is IE7 that is not right in IE8. Point to specific HTML elements or CSS rules that get failed to be applied to the elements.

Comment: I didn't describe it, cos it's obvious when you look at the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your markup? IE8 seems to think that the < p > tag under web applications isn't closed.

Comment: Yup. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: thanks dude. I was getting into one of those nightmare scenarios where you spend ages looking and just can't find the obvious stuff. Sometimes another pair of eyes is all it takes. Thanks again. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In all your script and css libraries, do any of them account for the html5 elements which IE7 and IE8 do not recognize? I give this as an answer rather than a comment because it may be the solution. If none do, then [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Comment: I used [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) which I assume takes care of that - it really is quite good.